# AWS Beanstalk Load Balancer to non HTTP port

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I created a AWS Beanstalk environment, which comes with the default url (my-env.something.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com) pointing to the load balancer on port 80. This is served by the default apache that runs on the instance I suppose.

On the instances, I also have Nginx running, listening on port 8001 (for my Django+Gunicorn app). When I use the above url with port 8001 (http://my-env.something.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:8001) in the browser, Nginx never gets the request. If I use the public IP of an instance instead it works fine.

Is what I am trying to do even supported ? To have the load balancer url go to any port on the EC2 ? Or do I need to create a new load balancer pointing to 8001 and use that instead ? How do I tell my beanstalk configuration then to use both load balancers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a new listener to the existing load balancer (from EC2 management console), selected listening port as 8001 and instance port as 8001. Also made sure the security group of the load balancer and instances matches up.

The load balancer url now works with both, the default HTTP port and 8001.